# what is the best way of querying a RDF model in jena in a generic way? (sparql or using collection and iterators)

Tags: java, rdf, semantic-web, jena

I want to create a slight generic query interface for my compiled RDF model.

I have to way of accessing my data :

1- using built in jena itertors / statemetns / resrources / etc ....

2-creating some SPARQL

but for creating SPARQL or RDQL I have to call a bind my SPARQL variables to java variables and since in my SPARQL I can have variety number of variables I don't know how to make it generic.

so what is the best way of making a RDF query interface generic?

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by "slight(ly) generic".

Comment: just for the sake of not to change my business logic so often. I want to create a slightly generic way of retrieving data from RDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SPARQL, not RDQL. Most systems today implement SPARQL that is the W3C standard. With SPARQL, as in SQL, you can use `*` to bind all the variable that occur in the triple patterns. Example:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
   ?s a :Person .
   ?s :name ?name .
   ?s :birthdate ?birthdate .
}
```

Most SPARQL client libraries allow you to get all variables. In Jena ARQ, for example, you'll find that `QuerySolution` has a method  `Iterator<String> varNames()`, this method will give you back all the variable names. You can traverse these and use the method `get` in the same class to retrieve the row values.

The great advantage of SPARQL is that, since it is a standard, you can use the different triple stores that follow the specification.

Comment: Thanks , I'll take your advice but out of curiosity I want to know how retrieve data using jena APIs(iterator/etc...) (its like nightmare to doing so...) what resource should I read for that matter? (jena DOC seems confusing specially for finding subclass of a class and things like that jena DOC won't help that much!)

Comment: If you'd like to send an email to the jena-users email list saying which bits of the documentation you found confusing, we can try to do something about it. Making generalised complaints that something isn't good enough makes it hard for us to improve what needs improving. To subscribe to jena-users, see http://incubator.apache.org/jena/help_and_support/index.html